# jQuery - Animate not working with first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Once the page loads, the first click on `#tab` triggers `.replaceWith` but not `.animate`. Both `.replaceWith` and `.animate` work properly from the second click on.

Any ideas?

```
$(function() {

    var open = false;
    $('#tab').click(function() {
        if(open === false) {
            $('#footer').animate({ top: '0px' });
            $('#openFooter').replaceWith('<h3 id="closeFooter">Click to Close</h3>');
            open = true;
        } else {
            $('#footer').animate({ top: '-85px' });
            $('#closeFooter').replaceWith('<h3 id="openFooter">Click to Open</h3>');
            open = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML markup code

Comment: can we see the html markup.. also host it on jsfiddle

Comment: Is the `#footer` element initially positioned to `top: -85px`?

Answer (score 0):

May be the footer is already open first time. Try setting the default value of `open` variable to `true`.

```
var open = true;
$('#tab').click(function() {
    if(open === false) {
        $('#footer').animate({ top: '0px' });
        $('#openFooter').replaceWith('<h3 id="closeFooter">Click to Close</h3>');
        open = true;
    } else {
        $('#footer').animate({ top: '-85px' });
        $('#closeFooter').replaceWith('<h3 id="openFooter">Click to Open</h3>');
        open = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason the function didn't like the initial false value. Changed the semantics and set the default to true and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your HTML and CSS, but my best guess is that `animate()` *is* getting called -- the issue is that the element is already positioned to `top: 0px`, so there is nothing to animate.

Post your HTML and CSS and I can provide a more definitive answer.